# How to mirror/cast Windows screens to RPi?

Tags: pi-3, windows

I have RPi 3 Model B V1.2 with Raspbian (PIXEL) OS.

I want to mirror my Windows OS screens/video/audio to my RPi.
I searched about this, I have found DLNA, UPnP, DIAL and etc... words.

But, I can't figure out that how actually mirroring/casting works in Windows.
Like for Apple, it uses AirPlay application. This application is an implementation of Bonjour and this Bonjour is an implementation of Zeroconf or DIAL.

By this, I can conclude that, I have to implement some kind of services/utilities which will support or use Zeroconf or DIAL on RPi. So, there is an Avahi service for this for Linux, which uses this type of configurations.

But, on Windows side, I don't know which type of services/protocols it uses or supports. That's why, I can't determine on RPi side about particular services or protocols.

**The ultimate goal is to mirror/cast** Windows screen from PC to RPi board (Not VNC). *Same like rPlay application, which runs on RPi and by using AirPlay on Apple device we can mirror our Apple device to RPi.*

If anyone knows then please share views and suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

In iOS, the AirPlay mirroring (which I think you're referring to) is built-in, and part of a protocol that Apple built. `rPlay` is an *implentation* of that, and isn't officially supported by Apple. Android has a similar feature with Chromecast, and I believe there's a Pi implementation of the Chromecast receiver with some limitations (no [DRM content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)). The **Bonjour** part of AirPlay *I believe* is just for discovery of devices on the same network (so that you don't have to put in the IP address of the TV every time you want to cast)

One way you could do it is with **VLC**, which has an incredible number of features. You can choose **Desktop capture** as in input device on your Windows computer, and choose to stream it over HTTP, then on the Pi *open* the HTTP stream (using the IP of your computer and the port number you selected, probably 8080) and it should display it. 
If you look at the VLC documentation, you should be able to create a windows shortcut on the desktop that launches VLC with all the right parameters to start streaming from the desktop, and a script on the Pi that starts playing the stream, I could expand on this if you want.

Another way is **built in to Windows**, so the only major configuration you need to do is on the Pi. With Windows you can use a *DLNA device* as an external display, which you can connect to [like so](http://www.howtogeek.com/233663/how-to-cast-websites-to-your-tv-from-microsoft-edge/) (under `Use Miracast or DLNA to Stream Your Desktop and Other Media`). You need to set up the Pi as a device that can *recieve a DLNA stream*, which is probably easiest using **Kodi** (formerly XBMC) and [enabling the UPnP client](http://kodi.wiki/view/UPnP/Client#UPnP_client_settings). The Pi *should* then show up as a device when using the above mentioned method to connect.

I hope this answer is useful, there was a lot of Google-fu involved and even I learnt something new today (the Windows DLNA support) that I might use myself!